# How to exclude specific category and show only one from the get_the_category();

Tags: wordpress

For example i have a post in category: cat1,cat2,cat3 and i want to exclude cat1 and show only one from cat2 or cat3.

```
 <?php
   $categories = get_the_category();
   $separator = ' ';
   $output = '';
         if($categories){
         foreach($categories as $category) {
         if($category->name !== 'Cat1'){
         $output .= $category->cat_name;}
         }
         echo trim($output, $separator);
         }
 ?>
```

I have tried this loop but it only works for excluding "Cat1" i also want to show one category from get_the_category(); ?

Can someone help me?

Comment: once you have your category(ies), you can retreive posts with `get_posts` (see [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for details). Note that if you want multiple categories, you would rather store their `id` than their names, separated with comas

Comment: How you decide this 'OR' 'only one from cat2 or cat3.' .. any random will work? in that case you might change $output .= $category->cat_name; to $output = $category->cat_name; it will overwrite cat2, with cat3 if cat3 exists.

Comment: cat 2 will be fine

Comment: @Mohsin  cat 2 will be fine

Comment: You may then check if($output != '') and then break the loop with "break" keyword. So as soon as $output has a value that will not be cat1 as skipped, but will be cat2.. so as soon it has that.. it just break the loop and move to next like i.e. echo trim...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 1):

**exclude category by using "exclude" argument with comma separated value category id in wordpress**

```
<?php
    $cat_args = array(
        'type'          => 'post',
        'parent'        => 0,
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => 0,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'exclude'       => '1,2,3',
        'include'       => '',
        'number'        => '',
        'taxonomy'      => 'category',
        'pad_counts'    => true 

    ); 
    $categories  = get_categories( $cat_args );
    if(count($categories )>0)
    {

       $separator = ' ';
       $output = '';
       foreach ( $categories  as $category ) {

             $output .= $category->cat_name;
             echo trim($output, $separator);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
     if($category->name !== 'Cat1'){
     $output = $category->cat_name;
    if($output != '') break; //end foreach when we have value
}
```